# How to distinguish 具に with 備に ?

Tags: word-choice, words

I bet this two words has the same meaning, and my prediction might be one of it are obsolete and the other one are frequently used by japanese people. Not just in this case, how to self-crosscheck kanji on a word whether obsolete or not?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check whether kanji are currently in use, you should use a Japanese native language dictionary.

I looked your words up in goo's dictionary (https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/147982/meaning/m0u/), because I was unfamiliar with both 具に and 備に.

If you look at their entry, it's written like this:

> つぶさ‐に【▽具に／▽備に／×悉に】 の意味

The x means that the character 悉 is not part of Joyo orthography (Government-mandated usage).

The down-triangle means the *reading* of the character is not approved by Joyo orthography. (Both 具 and 備 are characters in common use, but the reading is technically not approved).

Joyo doesn't seem to absolute dictate usage on the ground, but as a non-native speaker, I assume unless I frequently see otherwise, that one should not write things with the ▽ and that Japanese people will not even recognize x kanji.

Comment: @evanhutomo I am a native speaker, and I didn't know these kanji could be read as つぶさに :) You should stick to hiragana.

Comment: @naruto Thanks for your suggestion. Actually the whole word was like this つばさに日常を観察してみれば、いたるところに「あれ？」と思うマークや案内表示、但し書きを発見できるものだ。I learn japanese intensively since I came to hamamatsu 9 month ago, so I am new here. Every time I found word written by hiragana only, my guess is "that word was frequent to be used" and "because it was popular, the japanese usually write it in hiragana". I don't know my guess considered true or not, but please correct me if I wrong. Thank you in advance btw.

Comment: @evanhutomo Hmm, "popular" is not a good reason for writing something in hiragana. In modern Japanese, adverbs are usually written solely in kana. See [this](http://www.yamanouchi-yri.com/yrihp/techwrt-2-4s/t-2-4s03a.htm).